# Raspberry Pi- SPI with Hi-Res Bipolar ADC Chip (LTC1867). Wrong values being read

Tags: arduino, adc, raspberry-pi, spi

this is a follow up to my previous question "How to measure bipolar analog signal accurately (to 1mV) on raspberry pi" . I can't post more than 2 links yet but please have a look for some more background. The summary is that I need to measure a bipolar signal that varies between +/- 2V. I need the values to be accurate to about 1mV. After, asking here, I proceeded with what I thought was the best way which was to use the LTC1867 chip which is a 16 bit ADC that takes bipolar inputs to eliminate errors from level shifting circuits.

I tried to use the guides for connecting the MCP3008 to connect the IC to the raspberry pi. My connections were SCLK->SCK (Purple), MISO->SDO(Green), MOSI->SDI(Yellow), CE0->CS/CONV(Blue).
[image]
I used spidev for the SPI communication, because it looked like the most popular one (I didnt quite understand WiringPi). I tried to get a differential input between channel 0 and 1

[image: Input Data Word]

From the datasheet the input word would be 0000000X. And since it returns 16 bits I assumed I needed to send 2 8bit words. So I used spi.xfer2([0,0]). It returns 2 words. I shift the fist word by 8 bits and combine them both into one word. Since in bipolar mode, it returns it as 2's complement, I convert it to a normal number. However the answer I get is way off. So my questions are

1. Have I connected the ADC to the raspberry Pi correctly.
2. Am I sending and receiving the bits correctly?
3. How do I use Wiring Pi to communicate to the ADC or how do I communicate with ADCs that aren't MCP3008 and similar.
4. Lastly, while checking he SCLK signal on an oscilloscope, it showed no pulses. Any idea why?

PS: I can post my code as well but didn't want the question to be too long

Comment: It's not clear from your question, but are you aware that the conversion which is started when you clock that 7-bit control word in wil only have its result presented to you on the *next* SPI transfer? So the 1st set of data you receive will be a result of whatever the default settings in the LTC1867 produce, and the *next* set of data will be what you asked it for.

Comment: if possible add wiring circuit diagram from pi to LTC1867

Comment: @brhans I thought the spixfer2() returned the next set of data. So when I do spi.xfer2([0,0]) and it returns lets say [192, 224]. Are you saying I discard the 1 set of data (i.e 192)? If so, since I am expecting 16 bits back how do I get the remaining 8 bits because a 3rd set of data is never returned. Also the data sheet makes it look like the SDO returns only the bits I need. A bit confused

Comment: @Raj just added them

Comment: Each data set is 2 bytes, and send and receive occur simultaneously. So your first spi.xfer2([0,0]) sends a pair of 0's while simultaneously receiving whatever is presently in the LTC's results register. After that SPI transfer completes, the LTC begins a new conversion using the configuration you just sent it (0, 0). When that is complete you can read it out with another spi.xfer2([0,0]), and continue from there. The LTC can't give you the results of a conversion it has not yet done ...

Comment: **MOSI** (**M**aster **O**ut **S**lave **I**n) pins are used for sending SPI commands from master (MCU) to the slave chip (ADC or whatever). **MISO** (**M**aster **I**n **S**lave **O**ut) pins are used for receiving/reading data sent from slave chip (ADC) to the master (MCU). Check your connection according to this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any one has this problem, my suggestion would be to use an oscilloscope (or install piscope) to see what the MISO, SCLK, CE0,and MOSI are doing. Mine are behaving strangely[image]

My next task would be to find out why. I'm sure that would be the root of the problem.